# 2 similar graphs without rewriting the code

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts

I want to compare 2 versions of the same graph with slight changes, is there a way of doing that without having to write the code twice?

here's a simple example, having to write the same code two times:

```
values = [1,2,3]
labels = ['test1','test2','test3']

plt.figure()
plt.pie(values,labels=labels,startangle= 15)
plt.figure()
plt.pie(values,labels=labels,startangle= 90)
plt.show()
```

Comment: There's a great [matplotlib gallery example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/nested_pie.html#sphx-glr-gallery-pie-and-polar-charts-nested-pie-py) of two pie charts. They nest them because if you plot them both in the same place -- how do you see the underneath one?!?

Comment: Use a `for` loop with your parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you want to be able to look at two or maybe even more different angles using the same pie chart data.  You can do this with a loop as shown below.  If you just want 2 then you can just place two angles in the anglerange variable:

```
values = [1,2,3]
labels = ['test1','test2','test3']

#This is a list of different angles you want to plot
anglerange=list(range(0,180,30))
print(anglerange)

for i in anglerange:
    plt.pie(values,labels=labels,startangle= i)
    plt.figure()

plt.show()
```

[image]